# Invalid types 'double [100][double]' for array subscript

Tags: c++, arrays, types, double

```
#define MAX 100 
double velocity[MAX];
for (itr = 0; itr < velocity[0]; itr = itr + 1)
    {
        velocity[itr] = velocity[0] - (1*itr);
        distance[itr] = rk4_solve(itr, velocity);
        cout << setw(5) << itr << setw(9) << velocity[itr] << setprecision(4) << setw(10) << distance[itr] << endl;
    }
```

I am trying to input values into the array but for some reason I get the error: i Invalid types 'double [100][double]' for array subscript for the 3 lines inside the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itr` must be an `int` (or other integer type)

Be aware that you are comparing `itr` with `velocity[0]` in the for cycle (`itr < velocity[0];`). You probably meant `itr < MAX`, and I hope somewhere you defined the variable `itr`

Comment: I agree with this answer and would like to point out that, if this is not the case, then `velocity[0]` is undefined, so anything can happen at runtime.

Comment: @Gorpik +1 Considering he cut out various lines of code, I'm not certain of anything :-)

Answer (score 0):

A total shot in the dark, but could  you be missing a semicolon just above the lines shown?

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar issue.

Array index's cannot be double or float.

I fixed my issue by typecasting the index's to int.